# how to create divs rowwise in css

Tags: html, css

I want to create rowise block ie

---

|       | div2|
|div1   |div3 |
|_______|*div4|*

but when i try this that 'div2' goes below 'div1' i have tried display rowise
also div_container which holds all div1,div2,div3,div4 but it doesn't work
my html code

```css
#div_container
{
  height:325 px;
  width:600px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#div1
{
  height:325px;
  width:400px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#div2
{
  height:108px;
  width:200px;
  border-style: solid;
}
#div3
{
  height:108px;
  width:200px;
  border-style: solid;
}#div4
{
  height:108px;
  width:200px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_container">
  <div id="div1">
    </div>
  <div id="div2">
    </div>
  <div id="div3">
    </div>
  <div id="div4">
    </div>
</div>
```

please suggest me
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` to every box styles.

Comment: You can also just float it to the left with: "float: left;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add attribute display: and assign value to it inline-flex it will work

```css
#div_container
{
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new [display](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcssref%2Fpr_class_display.asp&ei=hunAVJCTCMbpaKPdgfAN&usg=AFQjCNHEDHzM-Yj-b0fv96WhM2pICbqA0g&sig2=mqXn_4ngrC3VpEV_bqaV-Q&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d2s) attribute in the container `div`must do the trick

```
#div_container
{
    height:325 px;
    width:600px;
    border-style: solid;
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: i added it in parent container it got applied  to div2. i want div 3 and div4 below div2

Answer (score 0):

Just add display:inline-block to inner div

css:

```
 #div_container>div{
    display:inline-block;

}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/38aamh8v/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
I have updated only the width of div_container (because you have applied the border and given fixed width that is 600px for main container and 400 for your div1 so div unable to take space or just remove the border) and applied the "display:inline-block;" for sub elements (div). please check jsfiddle example.
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Adalsingh/aLnkmLjo/)